# How to find how many string in other string

Tags: c#, winforms

I randomly trying to make this code works. The problem that I have is I can't find the string in some string, because char only takes one character.

Is there another way to do it?
e.g. I can find how many char `"e"` in `"excellent"`, But I can't find `"ll"`. It'll give me error.
The code which I use:

```
try
{
    int count = label1.Text.Split(Convert.ToChar(textBox1.Text)).Length - 1;
    MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
}
catch 
{
    messagebox.show("error");
}
```

Thats why I am using try to catch the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use `Convert.ToChar(...)` which is supposed to take only convertible `string` to `char` (that is, consists of a *single* character, but "ll" consists of *two* characters).

You could create an extension for `string` to do what you want:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static List<int> AllIndexesOf(this string str, string value) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("the string to find may not be empty", "value");
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int index = 0; ; index += value.Length) {
            index = str.IndexOf(value, index);
            if (index == -1)
                return indexes;
            indexes.Add(index);
        }
    }
}
```

And then just use it like:

```
int count = label1.Text.AllIndexesOf(textBox1.Text).Count;
```

Comment: where do i put this static class?. is there another way? seems complicated

Comment: You could use the more typical approach, yes. For instance, by having a method which takes two string (one original, one the phrase you want to find) as inputs rather than making a string extension. As for me, I would normally use `string` extension since it is slightly more complicated to set up but a lot easier to use. But if you use the approach above, you would normally put the static class in a C# file named `StringExtensions.cs`. You could put the `StringExtensions` class in your project's `namespace`.